# VBA to Copy from Named Range based on Condition to Paste Vlaues in another worksheet

Tags: excel, conditional-statements, copy-paste, vba

I have a Named Range "Quantities" (Worksheet Sheet1, cells I21:L28) that have formula that reports a the quantity in column "L".  I would like to search Column L for values >0, and then Paste those Values (along with Data from Column K) into another worksheet (Sheet10).
The following Code is close, but it paste the formula not the values.
Please assist.

```
Sub CopyOnCondition()
     Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, c As Range
     Set sh1 = Sheet1 'Edit sheet name
     Set sh2 = Sheet10 'Edit sheet name
     With sh1
         For Each c In .Range("L18:L24")
             If c.Value > 0 Then
                 c.Copy sh2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)(2, 1)
             End If
         Next
     End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below will copy the values only from Columns K:L when the value in column L > 0.

```
Sub CopyOnCondition()

     Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, c As Range
     Set sh1 = Sheet1 'Edit sheet name
     Set sh2 = Sheet10 'Edit sheet name

     With sh1
         For Each c In .Range("L18:L24")
             If c.Value > 0 Then
                 c.Offset(, -1).Resize(1, 2).Copy '<-- copy column K with L
                 ' paste values to the first empty row in Column A of sh2
                 sh2.Cells(sh2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlValues
             End If
         Next c
     End With

End Sub
```

Comment: AWESOME!  Works like a charm.  THANK YOU

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Sub CopyOnCondition()
     Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, c As Range
     Set sh1 = Sheet1 'Edit sheet name
     Set sh2 = Sheet10 'Edit sheet name
     With sh1
         For Each c In .Range("L18:L24")
             If c.Value > 0 Then
                 sh2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)(2, 1).resize(,2).value=c.offset(,-1).resize(,2).value
             End If
         Next
     End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Your `sh2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1)` is not fully qualified, `Rows.Count` without the `sh2` before means it's looking for the `ActiveSheet`. Also, the PO wants to copy values from Columns K:L , your code only copies the values from column K.

Comment: This worked too.  And I cannot tell the difference in the results.  Thank you both.